# Doubt on Token in Compiler Design

Tags: compilers

Say i have code snippet like -->

m -= n;

is **minus** and **assignment** considered as a single token or they will be considered as different token?

So the total token count will be 4 or 5?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you implement your compiler and for what language.

Comment: for c programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C language you cant insert space between '-' and '=', so you are better to implement '-=' as the single lexeme.

Comment: This is asinine. C standard is only an authoritative source of truth for an implementation of C.

Answer (score 0):

This has mostly to do with programming language design, not compiler design.

As an example, the C language defines that “-=“ is a valid token, and it also says that always the longest possible sequence of characters is used, so in the C language we gave a “-=“ token and not a “-“ token followed by a “=“ token.

The compiler is free to do what it likes but must of course translate the language correctly, so 99.99999999% chances that it creates a single token.

There’s an interesting situation in C++ where << can be used for nested templates. Not sure how the tokeniser would handle it, but the compiler must follow the language rules.